# Weird issue as scrolling mouse vertically in Salesforce Developer console moves the screen one line at a time. Any thoughts?

Tags: developer-console

When I scroll the mouse upward or downward inside Salesforce developer console, it moves the screen one line number at a time. This is happening in Chrome as well as in Microsoft Edge browsers. I tried with different mouse, restarted my machine nothing works. Resize, restore and maximize the browser to check if it adjusts or not. nothing works. Very weird. Any thoughts? Has anybody had this issue?

Comment: Salesforce Developer Console, or browser Developer Console?

Comment: @sfdcfox its Salesforce Developer Console. To avoid the ambiguity, I will edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: So, I got home and tested it, it works as it always have for me.

Comment: Could you check also on Firefox? SF Dev console tends to break... Normally using incognito mode on Chrome helps (something is cached) but maybe it just collided with browser engine (Chrome and Edge both run on Chromium). My normal approach in such cases is to... wait.

Comment: @user1974566 I have been waiting for more than 4 days now. I thought it was due to patch released by Salesforce. Ok, I will try with the options you suggested and will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for verifying. I will try in my personal laptop and other browsers as well.